# Yii 1.1: cross-controller variables (and even cross-view ones)

Tags: php, yii

For each request I have to load or, at least, create instance of a *MyUser*, which contains username, some internal permissions info, link to avatar and so on.

The thing is that I need this info for each and every controller and, for most of the views (to render or not to render some controls depending on user status and permissions).

It sounds like the need for a global variable, created at the time request being handled. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not familiar with DI implementation in yii, but you could certainly instantiate (or inject) MyUser in the constructor of your base controller, and pass it to your views.

Comment: @Steve That's the point - you always have to inject something, you basically need everywhere. Yep, it breaks DI principle, but what the heck... it makes development much easier and you are not able to test views anyway!

Comment: Well if you create (or inject) in base controller, and set it to a public property (`//constructor $this->somePublicProp = $user;`) then you can access in every view with `$this->somePublicProp;` so you never even need to type User in your inherited controllers, it is passed automatically

Comment: @Steve Why not an answer? I would be happy to upvote it! Thanks!

Comment: Well im not overly familiar with Yii, and thought someone else might have a better method using some kind of IOC that i didnt know about. However that doesnt seem to be the case, so i will write an answer now

Comment: @Steve, the question was about Yii1, it hasn't got The DI.

Answer (score 2):

Override CWebUser (which is what you call when you issue Yii::app()->user) with your custom class WebUser (placed in the components or other folder that has it's classes autoincluded), and define some getters like it is done with getRole() example below:

```
<?php
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    private $_model = null;
    function getRole() {
        if($user = $this->getModel()){
          return $user->userRole->name;
        }
    }
    private function getModel(){
        if (!$this->isGuest && $this->_model === null){
          $this->_model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }   
}
```

If you user the custom class instead of CWebUser, you have to explicitly tell which class to use in application's config:

```
'user'=>array(
    'class' => 'WebUser',
    // …
),
```

Comment: This is the answer for Yii1. Please name the version of Yii you are asking help for.

Answer (score 2):

You can create (or inject) an instance of `MyUser` in the constructor of your base controller, and set it to a public property:

```
//i am not familiar with Yii naming conventions, so ignore class name etc

class BaseController
{
    public $user;
    //presuming you can inject, if not $user = new MyUser();
    function __construct(MyUser $user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Then all controllers that inherit BaseController can access if they need to:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    function someAction(){
        $name = $this->user->name;
    }

}
```

And regardless of whether an action accesses the instance, its available in all views, without passing as a parameter to render:

```
//someview
echo $this->user->name;
```

Comment: I'd advise against it. It's a dirty trick - yii already has some sort of container we use throughout the application, Yii::app(), and a shortcut to the user component, Yii::app()->user. By declaring another user reference in controller, you go against the common sense - you are creating another shortcut. What is the point? Besides, afaik Yii1 haven't got DI, so you can't inject here.

Comment: @tebazil Yes, as i said in comments, i am not particularly familiar with Yii, and hope my answer isnt the best the OP gets. As to 'why bother' i believe the OP was frustrated by having to pass the user via render method in every action - if there is a better way to pass data to every view without explicitly doing so in every single controller action, then im sure the OP would be pleased to know about it. Perhaps it is acceptable to directly access `Yii:app()` in a view? Or you can somehow push data into view during constructor of controller?

Comment: Using Yii:app() in a view is perfectly fine, it's used that way in official yii sample application. It's an application-wide service locator. You will often be using to check Yii::app()->user->isGuest in a template to check whether user is logged in.